# angular 4 code coverage folder not created

Tags: angular, testing, karma-jasmine, code-coverage, angular-cli

I built my application with the angular cli version 1.1.1.  I am able to run my unit tests with `ng test` and I can see them running on the console and in the browser. Now I want to get a code coverage report.

I tried running `ng test --code-coverage` but no coverage folder was created.

Is there something else I need to do to get the code coverage to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

silly mistake... it turns out that I was starting the Karma test runner in the console but it wasn't automatically running the tests because a browser hadn't connected. Saving a file while ng test was watching the directory made it run the tests and create the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing a single run or does the watcher start at the end? Perhaps try to run `ng test --code-coverage --single-run`.

Comment: unfortunately it still doesn't create the code coverage folder